# IE9 "open in new tab" gives blank page

Tags: internet-explorer-9

When using IE 9 any time I right click to "open in new tab", or use any link that would normally do so I just get a new tab that is completely blank (a good example would be the Gmail print button which opens a cleaned version of the message in a new tab). No content, nothing in the title bar. I don't normally use IE but am trying to help a friend so don't know if it is an IE setting or MS security related.

Since asking this question I have lost access to this particular computer so won't be able to check answers.

Answer (score -1):

**I have same problem and this work for me(On windows 7 x64):**

I usually see this behavior when a Norton application is (or has been) installed and/or when one or more alternate browsers (e.g., Firefox; Chrome) have been installed changing the default Browser settings. Try the following fix:

Download/run the appropriate scripts by my colleague, IE MVP Kai Schätzl: http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en

Tip: The file named ie8-rereg.all.zip contains both of the scripts below.

2. Close all open applications (i.e., anything with an icon on the taskbar) then right-click on the script named ie8-rereg.32on64.cmd and select Run as Administrator, then reboot.
3. Close all open applications (i.e., anything with an icon on the taskbar) then right-click on the script named ie8-rereg.64on64.cmd and select Run as Administrator, then reboot once more.
4. IMPORTANT! => Now reset IE8 Advanced settings again per http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings, reboot one last time & test.

Comment: Dennis's question is about **Internet Explorer 9**. It is unclear (in your answer) if this solution worked for IE 9.